# How can I add an index on an attr_encrypted db field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, performance, postgresql, indexing

I have

```
attr_accessible :access_token
attr_encrypted :access_token, key: ENV['ENCRYPTION_KEY']
```

and I'm doing some `User.find_by_access_token`, so I'd like to index the field in the db.

However, no `access_token` exists, only `encrypted_access_token`.

Does indexing this do the same thing as indexing any other field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of saving encrypted data is to prevent the *cleartext* from showing. Obviously you cannot search for it, or the whole concept would be flawed.

You can index the *encrypted* token with a plain index and search the table with the *encrypted* token - for which you obviously need the encryption key.

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_encrypted_access_token_idx ON tbl(encrypted_access_token);

SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  encrypted_access_token = <encrypted_token>;
```

*If* all your tokens can be decrypted with an `IMMUTABLE` Postgres function, you could use an [index on an expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html):

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_decrypted_token_idx
ON tbl(decrypt_func(encrypted_access_token));

SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  decrypt_func(encrypted_access_token) = <access_token>;
```

Note that the expression has to match the expression in the index for the index to be useful.

But that would pose a *security hazard on multiple levels*.

Comment: Note also that you couldn't select for anything except equality. Ranges searches or pattern matches couldn't use such an index.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled and found a reference to [Fast Search on Encrypted Field](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Fast-Search-on-Encrypted-Feild-td1863960.html). A comment mentioned "deidentifying the data". Seems to be an [accepted method](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/coveredentities/De-identification/guidance.html).

Here's how I envision it working. In this example I separate the patient name from the rest of the Patient record.

`Patient Row: [id=1, name_and_link=9843565346598789, …]
Patient_name Row: [id=1, name=”John”, patient_link=786345786375657]`

The name_and_link field is an encrypted copy of two fields: the name and a link to the Patient_name. Having the name in both tables is redundant. I suggest it to provide faster access (no need to read from the Patient_name table). Also allows recreating the Patient_name table if necessary (e.g. if the two tables become out of sync).

The Patient_name table contains the unencrypted copy of the name value. The name row can be indexed for fast access. To search by name, locate matching names in the Patient_name table and then use the encrypted links back to the Patient table.

Note: In the example above I show long numbers as sample encrypted data. It's actually worse in real life. Depending on the encryption method, the minimum length of an encrypted value is about 67 bytes using Postgres' pgp_sym_encrypt() function. That means encrypting the letter "x" turns into 67 bytes. And I'm proposing two encrypted fields for each de-id'd field. That's why I suggest encrypting the name and the link together (as JSON tuple?) in the Patient table. Cuts the space overhead in half versus encrypting two fields separately.

Note: This requires breaking some fields into pieces. (e.g. phone numbers, SSN, addresses). Each part would need to be stored in a separate table. Even the street portion of an address would have to be further subdivided. This is becoming complicated. I'd like to see Postgres automate this.

Note: Just controlling access to the password is a tough issue itself.